# Skip Login View Controller in the NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tab bar which contains five tabs. My application does not required user to be logged in. Only some features will be allowed if a user signups or logins.

If a user registered/logged in already, I implemented the following logic in the `UserViewController` which is connected to the `NavigationController`. However, in the following logic, user still could able to see that ViewController in one-two seconds.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated 
 {
  if(isRegistered)
  {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UserProfileViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserProfileVewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
  }
}
```

I wonder if a user registered already, how could I skip UserViewController?
I want tabbar clicks to open directly to the `UserProfileVewController` rather than `UserViewController` which is login/signup viewcontroller.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the project's AppDelegate, you could check if user is logged/registered or not, and display the ViewControllers dependently:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    BOOL userIsLoggedIn = AMethodCheckIfUserLoggedIn();
    if (userIsLoggedIn) {
        UserProfileViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserProfileVewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    }
    else{
        UserViewController *userViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = userViewController;
    }

    //... Other logic goes here 

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try having your app delegate (or whomever you want really) conform to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and implement `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`. In there you might be able to do the necessary checks/fiddling of the view controllers maybe.